# Refresh component in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am fairly new to angular 2, and trying to learn more about it.

My question here is: **How do we refresh a component (re-invoke ngOnInit)**.

This component will be calling an API to retrieve some data from a database. and if a button is clicked, a PUT request will be sent to an API to update the data in the database. **Since the change happens in the database instead of the component itself, I dont think ngOnChange or other change checking method will work**. Here I am trying to let the ngOnInit be invoked again so the component can receive updated data.

I have tried router nagivate to refresh this page, but it does not work.

All the HTTP method happens in the another service file, I will not display them here since it's not relevant.

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([{path: 'data', component: DataComponent}]);
    ]
})
```

data.component.ts

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <button (click)= "onclick()">Click Me</button>
    `,
    ....
});

export class DataComponent implements OnInit{
    fetchData(): void{
        this.dataService.dataSessions().subscribe(
                data => this.data= data,
                error=> console.error(error),
                ()=> {}
        );
    }

     onclick(){
         this.dataChangeService.updateData().subscribe( response=> console.log(response));
         this.router.navigate['/data'];
     }

    ngOnInit(): void{
        this.fetchData();
    }
```

Any answer will be appreciated, I am always happy to learn more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call the this.fetchData() method once your call to the backend is resolved. Something like:

```
response=> { this.fetchData() ...
```

Comment: Great, glad it helped.

Comment: Sorry, but do you know how to refresh a parent component. I just realize its children component also has that button...

Comment: I cannot tell you exactly unless you provide a more concrete example. What you could do is add an @Output property in your child component and then emit an event to the parent once your call is resolved. On the parent, you can then take appropriate actions to refresh your data.

Comment: Wow, Awesome idea!

Comment: @Fjut I'm doing the same, but the Id is same in both the instance( When I'm calling the child Component in passing the Id, so while reloading also i'm passing the same id), so my ngOnchange() is not getting invoked is there any other possible way to just reload the child component while passsing the same Input value.

Answer (score -4):

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Inject,OnChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { ProductService } from '../../services/product.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router,NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router'
import { JQ_TOKEN } from '../../common/index'

@Component({
  selector: 'product-list',
  templateUrl: 'app/store/product_list/product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls:  ['app/store/product_list/css/style.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  products:any
  productcount : any
  sub:any;
  constructor(private productService:ProductService,private route:ActivatedRoute,@Inject(JQ_TOKEN) private $:any,private router:Router )     { 

  }


  ngOnInit() {
 this.productService.getProduct(this.route.snapshot.params['productcategory']).map(product=>this.products)
    this.products = this.route.snapshot.data['products']
   this.productcount=+this.products.length;

 this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
         this.paramsChanged(params['productcategory']);
       });   
  }
   paramsChanged(productcategory:string)
  {

       this.products = this.route.snapshot.data['products']
       this.productcount=+this.products.length;
    console.log('product list paramsChanged'  + productcategory);

     this.router.navigate['/store/'+productcategory];
  }


  }
```